# boost mpi serialization compress

Tags: boost, mpi, zlib

I am looking for a way to *compress* the *serialized data* in boost.MPI broadcast, scatter, gather requests. The class to be sent holds sizeable data (400MB) which needs to be transmitted over a wireless network. Although it does send, it takes >20 minutes. One way forward would be to compress the data, as is possible in a boost compressed archive (see below). Do you know whether similar compression methods exist for boost.MPI? If not, any suggestions on sending such amounts of data apart from implementing a fileserver?

**Example** of a class to be sent

```
class big {
    ...
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & big_element1;
        ar & big_element2;
    }
}
```

**Example** boost compressed archive

```
std::ifstream ifs(fname, std::ios::binary);
boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
in.push(ifs);
boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(in);
ia >> *this;
```

Comment: what is the question? You already have it done, it seems. Can you not hook up the serialization archive to the filtering stream?

Answer (score 1):

On sehe's recommendation, retried serializing to a stringstream, compressing that stringtream and broadcasting it as a string. Where I went wrong is in the order of adding the stringstream and decompressor to the stream buffer. Using the compress1 and decompress1 functions from [1](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/att-34343/main.cpp), the code looks as follows:

On the root node

```
std::stringstream sstr(std::stringstream::out);
boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(sstr);
archive << big_instance;
std::string str = sstr.str();
str = compress1(str);
broadcast(world, str, 0);
```

On the receiving nodes

```
boost::mpi::broadcast(world, str, 0); 
std::stringstream sstr(ecsim::string_decompress(str));
boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(sstr);
iarchive >> big_instance;
```